# Jpa hibernate and Table_Per_class inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have an entity that is super class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "super_class")
public abstract class SuperClass implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    public abstract void initDefaultValues();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

and some subclasses that extend the SuperClass.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Subclass1")
public class Subclass1 extends SuperClass{

    private static final Logger log = LogManager
            .getLogger(Subclass1.class);
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // testcase configuration tab
    private String configurationTabTestServer;


    private String umtsRelease;


}
```

The other classes look the same.

I used to have them SINGLE_TABLE for inheritance type but we wanted each concrete class to have each own table. Because of TABLE_PER_CLASS I had to use GenerationType.TABLE.

I also have an entity class that has a foreign key to the super class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myother_entity")
class Entity1{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SuperClass superclass;
    //more fields
}
```

I used an abstract class because I have one Entity1 class that could have different type of Superclass. We didn't want to create different Entity1 and Entity2 and Entity3 etc classes for each subclass. So we created one Entity1 class that can have a field of type SuperClass, that could point to any of the subclasses.

On my program I create many Entity1 intances that some of them that have different type of superclass as field value. Each could be of type subclass1 or subclass2 etc. At first we used to have one single table for all subclasses. Everything worked fine. But after we decided to split our tables this is what it happens. When I edit any Entity1 instance, that has already SuperClass field set(using one of the sub classes), and save it (merging it) then it creates a new instance of my Subclass associated with my Entity1 instance, and then saves it to the database. So I have two records now on the table of the subclass. This didn't happen when we used a SINGLE_TABLE inheritance type. Is this normal behaviour for JPA and hibernate?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it. Post your subclass entities too. I don't see why choosing a different inheritance type would have any impact on the ID generation strategy. I also don't see why you assiociate superclass with a table, since it's abstract, and you can thus only create instances of subclasses, that have their own table.

Comment: It does. JPA won't let you use AUTO, when you use TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance type.

Comment: By "JPA" you mean Hibernate, because the JPA spec says that "AUTO" is to be defined by the JPA provider as to which actual strategy they use. The only one it should be impossible to use is IDENTITY, and if the JPA provider sees AUTO it is perfectly at liberty to choose TABLE or SEQUENCE once it realises that it is TABLE_PER_CLASS

Comment: Yes sorry I ment Hibernate correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please, first consider this: DiscriminatorColumn and DiscriminatorValue annotations are specific to single-table approach. So they aren't to be used in table-per-class mappings.

Now, let's go to the issue:

In table-per-class mapping, there will be two records with same ID: one in a parent table, other in a child table.

As I understood, in your case, two records are being written in the child table, right? If so, the problem must be when you load the Entity1 data from the database. The property "superclass" must have its ID set. You can use eager or lazy loading for this. And check if that property is properly loaded (in debug mode) with its correct ID set before saving it.

Another way is to disable "cascade persist/merge" and to save the entities separately. It can provide more security to your data.

You can find more information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html

Comment: Discriminator value is a mistace, it doesn't exist on my actual code. Edited and corrected. First of all, hibernate won't create a table for parent class. And that is odd. I am guessing it is because parent class only has the id. It worked fine when I used the single table approach. Second I noticed that the table to generate the id's won't change the value in the value_column, the one that shows which the next id is.

Comment: JPA/Hibernate creates tables for both parent and child classes. Please, check your "hibernate.hbm2ddl" configuration. By the way, in large systems, I think it's better to make database changes outside hibernate/ORM.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the updates of the database. I am using Flyway for the ddl updateds. I know that everywhere it says that it creates one table per class (parent and child) but in my cases it doesn't. The onlyl thing different from the examples shown in web and mine is that my parent class has only the id field. I have tried to see what happens when hbm2ddl is "update" or "none" or "" but still the same.

Comment: @Apostolos, you told "hibernate won't create a table for parent class." Please, specify clearly what you need, so we can help you.

Comment: Thats ok thank you Raffael :). My problem was on my code. An object remained with id = 0 and I didn't update it after adding it to the database. The other issue that I said was a comment on whether hibernate creates a table for the parent abstract class when someone uses TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance. All examples on the internet say it does. But it didn't create on mine. And I wrote why I think it's happening. But this hadn't to do with my original question. I had a problem that hibernate created new object for every save, even when editing an already saved entity. A bug on my code it was :)

Comment: So fortunatelly it seems that you've found the answers! It's great! :)

Comment: I am a python django developer most, and I hate how complicated it seems to set up an orm in java using jpa and hibernate etc....SQLAlchemy i think is better thatn that...Anyways, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sometimes is really difficult to setup somethings, but as time passes, you get used to Java, and these kind of problems won't bore you anymore.